# Calculate boolean NumPy array with operator 'in'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to generate an boolean NumPy array from an one-dimensional array of integers (aka, shape is `(N,)`), if each integer is in a list using pure NumPy.

I could generate this array using this code:

```
valid = np.array([v in y_filter for v in y])
```

But my question is: is there any way to generate an array as 'valid' was generated using pure NumPy? I tried `y in y_filter`, but it throws this error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can't use `array.any` or `array.all`, because they only returns a boolean, and I can't select axis because there is only one axis.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `isin`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: Yes! You are right! I just understanded that `isin` is `is_included`. I thought it was something like `sin`. Thank you! You could post it as an answer: `valid = np.isin(y, y_filter)`